# How to view Firebase event parameter values?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, fabric.io

I have integrated Firebase Analytics in my project. I am logging around 10 different events. I can see all these events on the dashboard.

The issue is I am unable to see parameter values of the event.

Ex.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(AppConstants.PARAM_USER_ID, getUserId());
    bundle.putString(AppConstants.PARAM_OFFER_ID, itemDetails.getId());
    bundle.putString(AppConstants.PARAM_OFFER_TITLE, itemDetails.getTitle());
FirebaseAnalytics  mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("View_Item", bundle);
```

As per the above code, I can see the event named "View_Item" on the dashboard. But I can't see the details insight of each event's parameters like userId, item_id and offer title, etc.

Is there any way to see parameter values that?

Que 2. How long text parameter value can support?

Because I tried to log the event in Fabric with over 3k char. In this case, the content was getting cut and there no way to expand the full content in Fabric.

Is this same issue with Firebase?

Comment: You have to configure all params you want to see in Firebase Console for each event. There is 10 text and ~40 number params limit.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: This event parameter is useless. Should just use event_name to separate targets.